# A Puzzle About Mathematics

Tags: pattern

I am a student and I have an assignment to create an account, ask some sort of question and get points. Kindly give me some points or votes. Need your help and answer my question.
[image]

Find the missing number.

Comment: Please provide the source of this puzzle.

Comment: Your assignment is to get rep on Puzzling.SE?

Comment: actually we have to show our instructor the usage of stack exchange( that we asked questions and users reply our questions and give us votes). kindly vote my question thanks

Comment: If your assignment is to participate in stack exchange and see how it behaves and to get rep, you would be better off creating puzzles that follow the rules of the site and simply posting them without begging for rep. Also as stated by someone else If your puzzle is from an outside source you must include said source in the question or else it is considered plagiarism.

Comment: i dont know about the rules, can you help me

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> 10

Because

> Each point of the middle pentagon is the sum of the left and right pentagon points. So, $9+1=10$